# SharePoint 2007 : Get all list items in a list regardless of view from web service?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I need to check for duplicates. Currently I have items stored in sub folders in a list.

How can I retrieve all items in the list from a web service, so I can check for duplicates?

Here is code from object model: I want to do exactly this, but from a web service

```
private static void PrintItemTitles()

{

    string strUrl = "http://localhost:8099/";

    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strUrl))

    {

        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())

        {

            SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];

            SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;



            foreach (SPListItem item in items)

                if (item != null)

                    Console.WriteLine(item.Title);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: And what GetListItems return? As far I know it return everything not restricted by filter.

Comment: Requires a view field - if you don't pass a view field, it uses default - however, the default view because it includes folders, will never see sub items......

Comment: As per msdn documentation - viewName

    A string that contains the GUID for the view surrounded by curly braces ({}), which determines the view to use for the default view attributes represented by the query, viewFields, and rowLimit parameters. If this parameter contains an empty string, the default view is used.

Comment: Sorry, cannot help much, I do not have SharePoint installed for about one year. But can you still try GetListItems? What does it show? Because from memory, it should work.

Comment: Doesn't work - check the above comment. My list has items stored in folders, according to sharepoint - the default view is the top level folder only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SPList.Items doesn't return all items? Well, then try [SPList.GetItems(SPQuery)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx).

Have a following SPQuery:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID'/><FieldRef Name='Title'/>";
query.Query = String.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>", someItemTitle)
query.MeetingInstanceId = -1; //In case if you query recurring meeting workspace - get items from all meetings
query.RowLimit = 10; //Will you have more than 10 duplicates? Increase this value
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'"; //Also return items from folders subfolders
```

*Note: There could be some mistakes in code, because i`m writing from top of my head*

By executing this query and if it returns more than one item, then you have a duplicate!

### Edit: Ahh, sorry, you are talking about Web Services.

Then this code won't help. There are 2 options then:

Option 1: You CAN create a view that
   does include items even from folders
   (flat view). [See here for
   instructions](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=120).

Option 2: According to Lists Web Service's [GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx) method, you can pass QueryOptions parameter. Pass in

```
<QueryOptions>
   <MeetingInstanceID>-1</MeetingInstanceID> <!-- Again, if you query recurring meeting, you want ALL items -->
   <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' /> <!-- or Recursive if that does not work -->
</QueryOptions>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I used your code and created a custom web service - what a royal pain in the keyster

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Lists.asmx web service, but that is quite hard to do as it returns quite a lot of information. I would deploy a custom web service on my SharePoint environment that contains that code and returns the list items.